# K topology basic definition

Tags: general-topology

[can somebody please explain me the abstract meaning of the phrase "B be the collection of all open intervals (a,b), along with all sets of the form (a,b)−K" with some examples on real line???](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42348/k-topology-question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $K = \{\frac 1n: n=1,2,3,\ldots\}$. The set $B$ is a collection of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. Precisely, the elements of $B$ are all of the intervals $(a,b)$, together with the sets $$(a,b)\setminus K = \{x\in\mathbb{R}: a\leq x\leq b \mbox{ and } x\neq \frac 1n \forall n\geq 1\}.$$ So, for example, the interval $(-3,1)$ is an element of $B$. So is the set $(5,10)\setminus K$.